# How to make radio button and label in the same line using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add radio buttons through javascript dynamically as the number of radio buttons is determined run time. When I create radio buttons like this, radio button is getting displayed on top of label. But I want label to be displayed next to the radio button. Below is the javascript code.

```
  x = matchInfoArray[0];
  var values = [x.team1, x.team2];

  var selecttag1=document.createElement("input");
  selecttag1.setAttribute("type", "radio");
  selecttag1.setAttribute("name", "match1");
  selecttag1.setAttribute("value", values[0]);
  selecttag1.setAttribute("id","match1");
  var lbl1 = document.createElement("label");
  lbl1.innerHTML = values[0];
  div = document.getElementById("poll-content");
  div.appendChild(selecttag1);
  div.appendChild(lbl1);
  
  selecttag1=document.createElement("input");
  selecttag1.setAttribute("type", "radio");
  selecttag1.setAttribute("name", "match1");
  selecttag1.setAttribute("value", values[1]);
  selecttag1.setAttribute("id","match1");
  lbl1 = document.createElement("label");
  lbl1.innerHTML = values[1];
  div = document.getElementById("poll-content");
  div.appendChild(selecttag1);
  div.appendChild(lbl1);
```

'poll-content' is a div and css is as below.

```
 .poll-content input[type="button"]
{
    border: none;
    margin-top: 100px;
    outline: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #fb2525;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Can any one please help me how to fix this issue through javascript.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  *Element x displays on TOP of element Y instead of beside it*, many things can cause this.  `display:block;`, psuedo-elements, etc., etc..  A reproducible example would greatly help.

Comment: it's hard to imagine what you do. plesae make a snippet https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: From the top of my mind, try:
`lbl1.appendChild(selecttag1);
div.appendChild(lbl1);`.
Let me know if it helped/worked.

Comment: error on `selecttag1.setAttribute("id","match1");` (2 times) -> **id must be unique !**

Comment: @iAmOren: Thanks a lot. It did work. Can you please post this as answer.

Comment: @MisterJojo: Thanks. I will change that.

Comment: @iAmOren: It is working. But issue is label is getting displayed first instead of radio button.

Comment: It is working. I need to do lbl1.innerHTML += values[0];

Comment: Try the other way around:
`selecttag1.appendChild(lbl1);
div.appendChild(selecttag1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this kind of code, I prefer to use the DOMParser, it allows me to be sure of the result, and the code is cleaner, easier to correct or maintain.

```js
const DomParser   = new DOMParser()
  ,   pollContent = document.getElementById("poll-content")
  ;
function makeLabelInput( val, no)
  {
  let Elms = `
    <label> ${val}
      <input type="radio" name="match${no}" value="${val}">
    </label>
  `
  return (DomParser.parseFromString( Elms, 'text/html')).body.firstChild
  }


const matchInfoArray = [ { team1: 'team1', team2:'team2' }]
let indx = 0

pollContent.appendChild( makeLabelInput( matchInfoArray[indx].team1, indx) )
pollContent.appendChild( makeLabelInput( matchInfoArray[indx].team2, indx) )
```

```css
#poll-content label {
  margin-right: .5em;
  outline: none;
  padding: .2em .3em .2em .8em;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
  }
#poll-content input[type=radio] {
  transform: translateY(.2em);
}
```

```html
<div id="poll-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No doubt, Mr Jojo's answer works and is probably the *right* answer here. However, I would like to point out that you can basically achieve  a similar result with much less effort:

```js
const matchInfoArray = [ { team1: 'team1', team2:'team2' }];

document.getElementById("poll-content").innerHTML+=
  Object.values(matchInfoArray[0]).map(val=>
  `<label> ${val}
      <input type="radio" name="match0" value="${val}">
   </label>`).join("");
```

```css
#poll-content label {
  margin-right: .5em;
  outline: none;
  padding: .2em .3em .2em .8em;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
  }
#poll-content input[type=radio] {
  transform: translateY(.2em);
}
```

```html
<div id="poll-content"></div>
```

In my version I directly append the HTML to the already existing HTML of the target element. This *can* have the undesired effect of unbinding events from already existing children in the target. But, in case you have *not* used any direct attachment bindings on them then this method is a fast and easy way of creating the elements in question. In the above snippet I skipped the parametrisation of `indx` and hard coded it as `0`, as only this index seems to exist, but you can of course just as well wrap the expression with a `.map()` over all `indx` of the `matchInfoArray` elements.